# How to target a value if the element tree has the same name for one node in XML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulSoup in python3.

I have the following XML API response:

```
<allowed_media_types>
        <media_type>
          <media_type_id>3</media_type_id>
          <media_type_name>Hello World</media_type_name>
          <media_type_category_id>1</media_type_category_id>
          <media_type_category_name>Selfies</media_type_category_name>
        </media_type>
        <media_type>
          <media_type_id>55</media_type_id>
          <media_type_name>Bye World</media_type_name>
          <media_type_category_id>100</media_type_category_id>
       <media_type_category_name>All Types</media_type_category_name>
        </media_type>
      </allowed_media_types>
```

I am currently using:

response.find('media_type').find('media_type_id').string which only returns the first  node and the value 3. I want to be able gather as many  nodes as provided by this API response.

I am trying to figure out the best approach for this. The end goal is to capture all numerical values and pass along to another API request in its respective parameter. I appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find_all` which will return a list of all the elements it finds that matches those elements. You might be able to just directly call `soup.find_all('media_type_id')`, but I'm not sure of your entire XML structure and if you need to make sure it is under `media_type` or not, so we'll assume you must check if it is under `media_type`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
<allowed_media_types>
  <media_type>
    <media_type_id>3</media_type_id>
    <media_type_name>Hello World</media_type_name>
    <media_type_category_id>1</media_type_category_id>
    <media_type_category_name>Selfies</media_type_category_name>
  </media_type>
  <media_type>
    <media_type_id>55</media_type_id>
    <media_type_name>Bye World</media_type_name>
    <media_type_category_id>100</media_type_category_id>
    <media_type_category_name>All Types</media_type_category_name>
  </media_type>
</allowed_media_types>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print([node.find('media_type_id').text for node in soup.find_all('media_type')])
```

---

You could also use selectors and specify the `media_type` tag with a direct child (`>`) of `media_type_id`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
<allowed_media_types>
  <media_type>
    <media_type_id>3</media_type_id>
    <media_type_name>Hello World</media_type_name>
    <media_type_category_id>1</media_type_category_id>
    <media_type_category_name>Selfies</media_type_category_name>
  </media_type>
  <media_type>
    <media_type_id>55</media_type_id>
    <media_type_name>Bye World</media_type_name>
    <media_type_category_id>100</media_type_category_id>
    <media_type_category_name>All Types</media_type_category_name>
  </media_type>
</allowed_media_types>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print([node.text for node in soup.select('media_type > media_type_id')])
```

Output:

```
['3', '55']
```

Comment: This was super helpful! I ended up using your first recommendation. Thank you! @facelessuser

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.